# Can I re-enter the Sacred Grove on Zelda Twilight Princess?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

I'm playing Twilight Princess for the Wii. I just entered the Sacred Grove for the first time, fought the woods kid, and got the Master Sword. Reading the heart pieces guides, I see that I have to bomb a specific stone in the grove to get a heart piece (and a Poe's soul). Problem is, I got in without bombs.

I tried warping out and buying bombs, but I cannot get back in the grove: the wooden door is closed, and the triforce stone I howled to to enter doesn't react to proximity anymore.

Is it possible to get the heart piece afterwards? Or are there bombs in the area? Or can I move the stone by other means? My savegame is still inside the grove, if it helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can re-enter, but not until much later into the game. After which you can re-enter anytime you want. As for now, however, there is little you can do.